# SMTP header fortify issue code fix java

Tags: java, security, fortify

There is SMTP header manipulation issue in the scan report of HP fortify tool of my code.I have tried fix for replacing CRLF characters from subject line still issue exist in the report.
Can someone please let me know some other fix to resolve the issue.

Comment: For injection vulnerabilities you should whitelist rather than blacklist.

Comment: Can any one please suggest any other solution.I am still struggling with the fix.